# how do deserialize this json string to class

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have the following json string:

```
    {"Visits":[true,"DockedOnly","leftZone","0","500",0,0,0],
     "Weather":[true,"DockedOnly","leftZone","0","0",0,0,1],
     "ContactUs":[true,"DockedOnly","leftZone","0","317",0,0,2],
     "Birthdays":[true,"DockedOnly","middleZone","0","0",0,0,0],
     "Reminders":[true,"DockedOnly","middleZone","0","145",0,0,1],
     "Messages":[true,"DockedOnly","middleZone","0","0",0,0,2],
     "Availability":[true,"DockedOnly","middleZone","0","0",0,0,3],
     "Settings":[false,"DockedOnly","leftzone","0","155",0,0,0]}
```

Is there anyway to deserialize to something like the following?

```
    [Serializable]
    public class WidgetProps
    {
        public bool Visible { get; set; }
        public string DockState { get; set; }
        public string Zone { get; set; }
        public string Top { get; set; }
        public string Left { get; set; }
        public int UnusedA { get; set; }
        public int UnusedB { get; set; }
        public int Position { get; set; }
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class WidgetLayout
    {
        public WidgetProps Visits { get; set; }
        public WidgetProps Weather { get; set; }
        public WidgetProps ContactUs { get; set; }
        public WidgetProps Birthdays { get; set; }
        public WidgetProps Reminders { get; set; }
        public WidgetProps Messages { get; set; }
        public WidgetProps Availability { get; set; }
        public WidgetProps Settings { get; set; }
    }
```

or

```
    public class Widget
    {
        public string WidgetName { get; set; }
        public WidgetProps props { get; set; }
    }

    List<Widget> MyWidgets;
```

I am given the json string so I can't change how it is given to me but maybe I could tinker with it after I get it so it will work.

I tried:

```
    string s = "{\"Visits\":[true,\"DockedOnly\",\"leftZone\",\"0\",\"500\",0,0,0],\"Weather\":[true,\"DockedOnly\",\"leftZone\",\"0\",\"0\",0,0,1],\"ContactUs\":[true,\"DockedOnly\",\"leftZone\",\"0\",\"317\",0,0,2],\"Birthdays\":[true,\"DockedOnly\",\"middleZone\",\"0\",\"0\",0,0,0],\"Reminders\":[true,\"DockedOnly\",\"middleZone\",\"0\",\"145\",0,0,1],\"Messages\":[true,\"DockedOnly\",\"middleZone\",\"0\",\"0\",0,0,2],\"Availability\":[true,\"DockedOnly\",\"middleZone\",\"0\",\"0\",0,0,3],\"Settings\":[false,\"DockedOnly\",\"leftzone\",\"0\",\"155\",0,0,0]}}";
    var sd = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize < List<Widget>>(s);
```

and

```
    var sd = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize < WidgetLayout >(s);
```

Comment: Looks like a good start to me. What happens when you try this?

Comment: using first option I get "Invalid object passed in, ':' or '}' expected. (2): {{"Visits": true,"DockedOnly","leftZone","0","500",0,0,0],"Weather":"....

Comment: @SimonWhitehead I'm assuming the issue is that the arrays in json contain different types which isn't very compatible with C# where collections are strongly typed.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal I was just making sure the OP had tried it and wasn't asking us to do the work for them :P

Comment: The solution is going to be gross. You're just going to have to deserialize into object arrays and then do a lot of casting...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't working because you're trying to deserialize an array into an object. The json.NET deserializer will not be able make that conversion.

Because your json arrays have multiple types in them you'll have to deserialize into the smallest common denominator, in this case, `object`. From there I would recommend writing a method to assign each index to it's corresponding property in WidgetProps.

So basically, define this constructor;

```
public WidgetProps(object[] props)
{
    Visible = (bool)props[0];
    DockState = (string)props[1];
    // ext
}
```

I would have something like a `WidgetDirty` class that I do the initial deserilization into. From there you can create a new instance of `WidgetLayout` by instantiating each of it's properties like `myWidgetLayoutInstance.Visits = new WidgetProp(myWidgetDirtyInstance.Visits);` I'd probably hide this mess in a `WidgetLayout` constructor that takes a `WidgetDirty` as it's only arg.

yes it's disgusting... but I don't know of any real alternatives because that json's design just isn't very compatible with the C# language. If you're strongly apposed to this I might look at the `dynamic` type. I haven't used it in C# and probably never will, but I know that deserializing that in a dynamic language like PHP would be no trouble at all.

Comment: Is it that JSON isn't compatible with C# language, or that what he is trying to deserialize isn't a very well designed JSON object?

Comment: @mikey json is very compatible with C#, it's just that json's design. I'll edit to make that sentence more clear.

Comment: I will try this approach... and will post final outcome based on this answer.

Comment: @mikey I think that it's that this is simply a badly designed JSON, it has nothing to do with compatibility with C#. Arrays should be homogeneous, each index shouldn't have its own separate meaning, that's what JSON objects are for.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work, because array is normally not deserialized as an object. If possible, I think you should fix the JSON. If you can't do that, and you're using JSON.NET, you can create `JsonConverter` for `WidgetProps` that manually converts the array to the object:

```
class WidgetPropsConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override void WriteJson(
        JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    public override object ReadJson(
        JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue,
        JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var array = serializer.Deserialize<object[]>(reader);
        return new WidgetProps
        {
            Visible = (bool)array[0],
            DockState = (string)array[1],
            Zone = (string)array[2],
            Top = (string)array[3],
            Left = (string)array[4],
            Position = (int)(long)array[7]
        };
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(WidgetProps);
    }
}
```

You would then use it like this:

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<WidgetLayout>(
    jsonString, new WidgetPropsConverter());
```

Comment: @ginalster (comments to my post are incorrectly on a deleted answer). It works for me with your `WidgetLayout` and `WidgetProps` classes.